Links to files/folders and intra-file links in files compilable as C#?
I have a C#-project that scans a folder for files and then extracts information from those (several hundred) files and then inserts the extracted information to a single C#-file. This generated C#-file is then used by a second C#-project, that calls the first project's exe-file upon pre-build. The auto-generated file is quite large and I would like to somehow achieve the following to make it easier to navigate inside it:

Clickable links to different parts within the file, similar to what some webpages have (image a table of contents in the beginning of the file and if you click a row there you'll be taken to the corresponding section).
Clickable links to files and folders on the harddrive (that were used to extract information from).
It's ok to use a tool/viewer other than Visual Studio to view the file in, for example a standard web browser. I have managed to make an html-file with embedded C#-namespace and C#-classes, but I can't make Visual Studio recognize it as a C#-file since it has the wrong file extension (html instead of cs). Can anyone please help me?


What is the actual goal of this? It sounds like a highly unusual workflow, and may indicate an XY-problem, so you probably want to explain why this solution is the best solution for whatever actual problem you are trying to solve.

The goal is to be able to verify and check the information extracted from all the files in an easier and faster way.

That does not explain your actual goal. Why are you inserting information in a c# file in the first place? What type of data are we talking about? Why are you not loading this data at runtime instead?

The data is configuration for microcontrollers, DSP, codecs, etc. The raw files, which are company confidential, are in bin, xml and txt formats. The exe-file of the second project is distributed to our customers and distributors and the file size should be kept to a minimum.

That does still not explain why you are inserting information into a c# file. If you need to bundle data with your application there are plenty of ways to do it that does not involve code generation. And I fail to see how adding information into source code would improve either security or file size.

The bin, xml and txt files contain metadata that is excluded when the information is extracted and the data is converted to byte arrays instead of mostly ASCII. I'm sure there are other way to do this, but I wanted to do this with as few files as possible. I want to distribute ONE exe-file that can be run directly from e.g. a USB-stick if necessary, I don't want the application to require an installation. I'm sure the ambitious hacker could extract the relevant bytes and reverse engineer what chips and registers those bytes are written into, but this is an acceptable solution for our needs.
